# как в одну строку "сцепить" список букв в строку?

Tags: python, строки

Объединение строки не работает. То есть вместо ожидаемого ["HELLO"] я получил ['H','E','L','L','O']

```
def find_message(text):
    """Find a secret message"""
    y = [''.join(x) for x in text if x.isupper()]
    return y[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # These "asserts" using only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-testing
    assert find_message("How are you? Eh, ok. Low or Lower? Ohhh.") == "HELLO", "hello"
    assert find_message("hello world!") == "", "Nothing"
```

Свою ошибку понял. Но хочется сделать в одну строку хотя бы  ["HELLO"]  из ['H','E','L','L','O'] в следующей строке. Подскажете?
Как собрать через цикл - понятно )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Список тоже нужно в строку превращать:

```
def find_message(text):
    """Find a secret message"""

    return ''.join(x for x in text if x.isupper())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # These "asserts" using only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-testing
    assert find_message("How are you? Eh, ok. Low or Lower? Ohhh.") == "HELLO", "hello"
    assert find_message("hello world!") == "", "Nothing"
```

---

Тот же алгоритм, но через регулярку:

```
import re

def find_message_v2(text):
    """Find a secret message"""

    # return ''.join(re.findall(r'[A-Z]', text))
    # OR:
    return re.sub(r'[^A-Z]', '', text)
```

---

Тот же алгоритм, но в функциональном стиле:

```
def find_message_v3(text):
    """Find a secret message"""

    return ''.join(filter(str.isupper, text))
```

Comment: Может re.sub(‘[^A-Z]+’, ‘’, Text)  ?

Comment: Удалить все символы, кроме A до Z? А почему бы и нет -- выглядит хорошо :)

Comment: как говорится - я все знаю, только не летаю )) Благодарю!